# wso2 cep sequence detect missing event

Tags: events, wso2, complex-event-processing

I would like to define a query in cep/siddhi that detects a missing event in a sequence.

I have 4 events that must occur within 5 minutes. (p1->p2->p3->p4 within 3000)

How can I write the condition to insert my alert event when one of the p2,P3 or P4 is missing within the 5 minutes time window after p1 occurs ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there's no direct way of detecting non-occurrences. However, this can be accomplished by writing a custom window and then writing a query that uses the custom window.

Please refer the link below for more info on how to write a custom window for WSO2 CEP:

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/CEP210/Writing+Extentions+to+Siddhi